# $X \sim U(0,1), Y \sim U(X,1)$, what is $E(Y^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, uniform-distribution

$X,Y$ are both Continuous uniformly distributed.

What is the method to find $E(Y^2)$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: don't you rather mean $Y\sim U (X,1)$ ?

Comment: Hint: this is an exercise in conditional expectations; since as @Surb notes $Y\sim U(X,\,1)$, if you compute the function $f(x):=E(Y^2|X=x)=\int_x^1\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-x}}y^2dy$ (the blue part being $Y$'s pdf on $[x,\,1]$) then $E(Y^2)=E(f(X))=\int_0^1f(x)dx$.

Comment: What does $U(X,1)$ mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $Y\sim U(X,\,1)$ is abuse of notation for $Y|X=x\sim U(x,\,1)$.

Comment: $Y\mid X\sim\mathcal U(X,1)$ is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

As commented this is just a matter of using the Law of Total Expectation.

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y^2) & =\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y^2\mid X))\\&=\int_\Bbb R\left(\int_\Bbb R y^2\,f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,\mathrm d y\right) f_{X}(x)\,\mathrm d x\\ &=\int_0^1\int_x^1\frac{y^2}{1-x}\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$